# What's the difference between 'ideal' and 'actual' rewards?

Tags: rewards, documentation

I got info 'ideal' and 'actual' rewards in the tezos rewards distributor software. Searched the docs, didn't manage to find anything meaningful.

Comment: What does the "tezos rewards distributor software" refer to?

Comment: @Eugen, "tezos rewards distributor" (aka TRD) is the most popular payouts software for Tezos. https://github.com/tezos-reward-distributor-organization/tezos-reward-distributor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these terms are explicitly explained in the docs: https://github.com/tezos-reward-distributor-organization/tezos-reward-distributor/blob/master/docs/configuration.rst